# Include function returns error saying A specified Include path is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to get Products data with a relational table data called- Transections. But when I try to use `.Include` like below I am getting an error. Please give me hints and tell me how can I fix it?

```
using (var ctx = new ML_DatabaseEntities())
{
    var Items = ctx.Products.Include("Transactions").ToList();
}
```

> Error: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'ML_DatabaseModel.Products' does not declare a navigation property
>   with the name 'Transactions'.

Comment: You model does not define this relationship you have to explicitly state it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a one-to-many relationship between `Product` and `Transactions`. So you need to add navigation property to `Product`:

```
public class Product {
  public int ProductID { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `Transaction` class should look something like this:

```
public class Transaction {
  public int TransactionID { get; set; }
  public int ProductID { get; set; }
  public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
using (var ctx = new ML_DatabaseEntities())
{
    var Items = ctx.Products.Include(p => p.Transactions).ToList();
}
```

For more insights check you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) (EF6 not Core)